# Javascript Shift-Click checkboxes To Do App

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I'm currently building off Wes Bos Javascript 30 project. 
Turned the project into a to-do app. And I can't figure out how to use the shift-clicking on newly created checkboxes using vanilla javascript.

Any insight on how to do this?

```
const addBtn = document.querySelector('.addBtn');
const myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
const toDo = document.querySelector('.toDo-container');
const checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('.toDo-container input[type=checkbox]');

addBtn.addEventListener('click', newElement);

myInput.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){ 
  if(e.keyCode === 13){
  e.preventDefault()
  newElement() }
});



// Create a new item when clicking on the "Add" button
function newElement(){
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  let input = document.createElement('input');
  let inputValue = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
  let textNode = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  let p = document.createElement('p');

  div.className = "item";
  input.type = "checkbox";

  p.appendChild(textNode);

  div.appendChild(input);
  div.appendChild(p);

  toDo.appendChild(div); 

  if(inputValue !== ""){
     document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";
  }


}

// Shift Clicking Checkboxes.
let lastChecked;

function shiftClick(e){
    let inBetween = false;
    if(e.shiftKey && this.checked){
      checkbox.forEach(box => {
        if(box === this || box === lastChecked){
          inBetween = !inBetween
        }
        if(inBetween){
          box.checked = true;
        }
      });

    }
    lastChecked = this;
  }

checkbox.forEach(box => box.addEventListener('click', shiftClick));
https://codepen.io/iameddieyayaya/pen/XGWaQN?editors=1011
```

Thanks a ton!

Eddie G.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a flag when the shift key is pressed and reset it when the key is released. Then your click listener can just act conditionally based on the state of the flag. (I don't know if focusing the whole container as I've done here is the best way to ensure that you don't fail to notice any keystrokes, but it works.)

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const box = document.getElementById("box");
let shiftIsDown = false;

container.addEventListener("keydown", setShiftFlag);
container.addEventListener("keyup", setShiftFlag);
box.addEventListener("click", handleBoxClick);

container.focus();

function setShiftFlag(event){
  if(event.code == "ShiftLeft" || event.code == "ShiftRight"){
    if(event.type == "keydown"){
      shiftIsDown = true;
    }
    else if(event.type == "keyup"){
      shiftIsDown = false;
    }
  }
}

function handleBoxClick(){
  if(shiftIsDown){
    console.log("shift-click");
  }
  else{
    console.log("click");
  }
}
```

```css
body{ height: 100px; }
#container{ width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container" tabindex="0">
    <input type="checkbox" id="box" />
  </div>
</body>
```